# How to properly set the path in Windows Vista cmd using batch file?

Tags: windows-vista, batch-file, command-prompt

I am a complete newbie when it comes to programming and some basic computer concepts so pls be patient with me if my question might look so silly.

I am trying to create a batch file command that will automatically redirect me to a particular directory. What happens is that when I call the batch file it will only display the path but still in the same directory. I am doing this for shortcut purposes.

This is the default directory whenever I open my cmd-prompt (I don't want to change the default):

> C:\Users\eacomm>

Here's the command that I typed and saved it as **`setpath.bat`**:

> path=C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\cakephp;

Here is the result whenever I call **`setpath`**  and hit **ENTER**:

> C:\Users\eacomm>C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\cakephp;

I want to redirect this one... Whats wrong with this??? Pls help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't use simply:

```
cd C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\cakephp
```

inside your .bat file?

Comment: Thanks man... I wasn't able to think about that... I am such a total noob that everyting I read on the nternet I follow... Thanks so much